# Adjust "max_detection_per_class" for every class in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am training an object detection algorithm using the Tensorflow Object Detection API. I am currently using the vanilla version of the config files, I just changed what was absolutely necessary to make it run.
Now I would like to change the maximum number of detections per class, but depending on the class.

Let me explain:
Suppose my classes are `["cat", "dog", "bird", horse", "mouse", "car", "bicycle", "truck", "motorbike", "train"]`. And I know from my use case, that on the picture there can only be one of the transport vehicles (they are mutually exclusive) and 0 to 10 animals. Is there a way to adapt the config file in a way that I can train the network with those limitations? Because the only parameter I see is a generic `max_detections_per_class`.

Here is my .config-file for reference.

```
 # SSD with EfficientNet-b0 + BiFPN feature extractor,
# shared box predictor and focal loss (a.k.a EfficientDet-d0).
# See EfficientDet, Tan et al, https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.09070
# See Lin et al, https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002
# Trained on COCO, initialized from an EfficientNet-b0 checkpoint.
#
# Train on TPU-8

model {
ssd {
inplace_batchnorm_update: true
freeze_batchnorm: false
num_classes: 10
add_background_class: false
box_coder {
faster_rcnn_box_coder {
y_scale: 10.0
x_scale: 10.0
height_scale: 5.0
width_scale: 5.0
}
}
matcher {
argmax_matcher {
matched_threshold: 0.5
unmatched_threshold: 0.5
ignore_thresholds: false
negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
force_match_for_each_row: true
use_matmul_gather: true
}
}
similarity_calculator {
iou_similarity {
}
}
encode_background_as_zeros: true
anchor_generator {
multiscale_anchor_generator {
min_level: 3
max_level: 7
anchor_scale: 4.0
aspect_ratios: [1.0, 2.0, 0.5]
scales_per_octave: 3
}
}
image_resizer {
keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
min_dimension: 512
max_dimension: 512
pad_to_max_dimension: true
}
}
box_predictor {
weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
depth: 64
class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
conv_hyperparams {
force_use_bias: true
activation: SWISH
regularizer {
l2_regularizer {
weight: 0.00004
}
}
initializer {
random_normal_initializer {
stddev: 0.01
mean: 0.0
}
}
batch_norm {
scale: true
decay: 0.99
epsilon: 0.001
}
}
num_layers_before_predictor: 3
kernel_size: 3
use_depthwise: true
}
}
feature_extractor {
type: 'ssd_efficientnet-b0_bifpn_keras'
bifpn {
min_level: 3
max_level: 7
num_iterations: 3
num_filters: 64
}
conv_hyperparams {
force_use_bias: true
activation: SWISH
regularizer {
l2_regularizer {
weight: 0.00004
}
}
initializer {
truncated_normal_initializer {
stddev: 0.03
mean: 0.0
}
}
batch_norm {
scale: true,
decay: 0.99,
epsilon: 0.001,
}
}
}
loss {
classification_loss {
weighted_sigmoid_focal {
alpha: 0.25
gamma: 1.5
}
}
localization_loss {
weighted_smooth_l1 {
}
}
classification_weight: 1.0
localization_weight: 1.0
}
normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
post_processing {
batch_non_max_suppression {
score_threshold: 1e-8
iou_threshold: 0.5
max_detections_per_class: 100
max_total_detections: 100
}
score_converter: SIGMOID
}
}
}

train_config: {
fine_tune_checkpoint: "C:/Users/pretrained_models/efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
batch_size: 8
sync_replicas: true
startup_delay_steps: 0
replicas_to_aggregate: 8
use_bfloat16: true
num_steps: 20000
data_augmentation_options {
random_horizontal_flip {
}
}
data_augmentation_options {
random_scale_crop_and_pad_to_square {
output_size: 512
scale_min: 0.1
scale_max: 2.0
}
}
optimizer {
momentum_optimizer: {
learning_rate: {
cosine_decay_learning_rate {
learning_rate_base: 8e-2
total_steps: 20000
warmup_learning_rate: .001
warmup_steps: 2500
}
}
momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
}
use_moving_average: false
}
max_number_of_boxes: 100
unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
}

train_input_reader: {
label_map_path: "C:/Users/models/research/object_detection/training/label_map.pbtxt"
tf_record_input_reader {
input_path: "C:/Users/models/research/object_detection/train_20221021_143516.record"
}
}

eval_config: {
metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
use_moving_averages: false
batch_size: 1;
}

eval_input_reader: {
label_map_path: "C:/Users/models/research/object_detection/training/label_map.pbtxt"
shuffle: false
num_epochs: 1
tf_record_input_reader {
input_path: "C:/Users/models/research/object_detection/test_20221021_143516.record"
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible. My guess is it isn't, I might be wrong though. I think you might be able to resolve the exclusivity in the postprocessing after you get the prediction candidates from the model.

Comment: @LadislavOndris thanks for the feedback. Maybe that is an alternative approach, thanks for pointing it out. But I would prefer to train the network "properly", if it is possible.

Comment: The max_detections_per_class does not impact training, it's only in the post processing phase. You might have to run your tailored version of the Non Max Supression algorithm for each class, which I don't believe is possible directly through the Tensorflow Object Detection API.

Comment: @CrazyEngineer If you want to introduce exclusivity to the model directly during training, then you can modify a loss function to penalize the model for predicting non-exclusively. How to modify a loss in the object detection api was discussed here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/7817. 
That said, I can't say which approach is best.

Comment: @LadislavOndris thanks! But if I understand correctly, that would penalize any kind of non-exclusivity, but I need exclusivity only for certain classes.

Comment: @Lescurel Thank you! In this case, I will try to modify the post processing.

Comment: @CrazyEngineer I believe you could add the penalization term in the loss function only for the classes you want. The model predicts N detections per class, so for the penalization term, you would take from the tensor only the classes that should be exclusive and compute the term from that.

But the postprocessing might be just easier.